# Deploy thousands of files to FTP during web app deployment process

Tags: php, apache, deployment

Recently I investigated the continuous integration development process, so I installed a TeamCity server, set up the build and tried to make it automatically deploy the build artifacts (my web app) to the web hosting server through FTP. However, I failed on the last step (deployment) because of thousands php files deploying for a very long time. So, I'm wondering if there is a way to do it more quickly, perhaps using zip-archives or something else.

So, my question is, if there is a common way to solve such problem?

Comment: git svn perhaps.

Comment: Many deployment technologies deliver a new version to the production environment in a bundle. The bundle's inflated/unzipped into a staging directory parallel to the production directory. Sometimes in the case of web apps, the production code is accessed via a symlink, and that symlink is then updated to point to the staging directory. So it's a seamless transition.

Comment: Yes, I know it is possible, for example, for Java servlet apps using WAR archives. But my question is about Apache servers running php apps

Comment: Just an additional comment to the git proposals: If you'll use git, and you'll notice that it becomes (too) slow in regard auf deploying to a remote repository, then I would recommend you to try the _FreeFileSync_ app.

Comment: I think you didn't get the idea. I'm using git right now, but git is used for version control purposes. And I'm talking about application deployment to web server.
Are you proposing to setup git repo on the server? There is no sense in doing that, though I couldn't do it even if wanted to. When you're using some web-hosting provider services, you can't setup git repo just because there is no git installed

Comment: Another one-word answer: `rsync`

Comment: @Sini4ka I saw that you have doubts regarding git. Well, not only that you can setup a remote git repository on the/a remote web server, but you actually should do this. And, besides version control, the truly power of the git's capability comes from the fact that it can be applied in distributed systems. [Read Chapter 4 - Git on the Server](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-on-the-Server) and [Chapter 5 - Distributed Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Distributed-Git) of the official git book.

Comment: @Sini4ka Indeed, not all web hosting companies provide git as one of their services. But, in fact, you should choose a provider that does it. Personally, I know at least one web hosting provider - 1&1, that gives you the git chance. [Here](https://hasin.me/2014/05/23/remote-deploy-using-gits-server-side-hooks/) is a little help for you, to see how to setup the remote repository and how to "deploy" your local project's changes to it using hooks. The hook is actually represented by 2-3 lines of code in a file which you'll create on the remete webserver.

Answer (score 1):

Use git for deploy. It get only changes

Example using hooks: gist.github.com/noelboss/3fe13927025b89757f8fb12e9066f2fa – Łukasz Gawrylu

Comment: This is easy to setup and works well, but it needs to be configured properly. Otherwise you might leave your repo history and other non-production assets on a production server.

Comment: Git for deploy? How could I do that?

Comment: Example using hooks: https://gist.github.com/noelboss/3fe13927025b89757f8fb12e9066f2fa